# room query about rleations

Tags: android, entity-relationship, android-room

Suggest there are tables below:

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9dUi.png)

How can i query all categories containing posts(`List<CategoryPost>`) by a sql.

CategoryPost:

```
data class CategoryPost(
        @Embedded
        var category: CategoryEntity,
        var posts: List<PostEntity>
)
```

Other entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_category")
data class CategoryEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Long,
        var name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "tbl_post")
data class PostEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Long,
        var title: String,
        var content: String,
        var createTime: Long,
        var authorId: Long
)

@Entity(tableName = "tbl_post_category")
data class CategoryPost(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long,
        var categoryId: Long,
        var postId: Long
)
```

I learned about google's doc about [@Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html), but there are only two tables shown in that sample. And Pet table contains `userId` column whitch used in query as entityColumn.

So, must i remove my tbl_post_category table and add a coloumn of category_id to tbl_post table if i want to query `List<CategoryPost>` by a sql?